# Source code won't download from SoundCloud

Tags: html, vb.net, webclient

Whenever I try download the source code from this website:

https://soundcloud.com/search?q=Song

It does not appear to work. Even if you attempt to view the page's source, it will not work. It is simply the source code of a webpage which says that the page does not exist. If anyone knows why this happens I'd greatly appreciate it as I am working on a programming in VB.Net and it's the only issue I have come across so far.

Here is the code I am using:

```
 Dim source As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://soundcloud.com/search?q=Song")
```

Thank you for your time. Just a note: I have tried using WebRequests and even a WebBrowser, though the WebBrowser appears to just show a blank webpage.